# in R calculate mean speed of specific data range conditionally

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, mean

I need to calculate the mean walking speed grouped by the attribute **type**. But only as long as the observations are chronologically in the same order. So if the type is not trip, the next "cluster" of trips has an other mean.

Here is a data sample:

```
1   Time    speedms     type        
1   1:12:21 1.0978790   trip    
2   1:12:22 1.5707432   trip    
3   1:12:23 1.0745824   
4   1:12:24 1.1682027   
5   1:12:25 1.3859502   
6   1:12:26 0.9657960   trip    
7   1:12:27 1.2591893   trip    
8   1:12:28 2.0004471   trip    
9   1:12:29 2.2239989   
10  1:12:30 1.6928664   
11  1:12:31 2.8167094   trip    
12  1:12:32 3.7848781   trip    
13  1:12:33 0.4496923
```

And this is the structure I want. A new column (mean) with the mean per cluster for each observation in this cluster.

```
1   Time    speedms     type        MEAN
1   1:12:21 1.0978790   trip    1.334311
2   1:12:22 1.5707432   trip    1.334311
3   1:12:23 1.0745824   
4   1:12:24 1.1682027   
5   1:12:25 1.3859502   
6   1:12:26 0.9657960   trip    1.408477
7   1:12:27 1.2591893   trip    1.408477
8   1:12:28 2.0004471   trip    1.408477
9   1:12:29 2.2239989   
10  1:12:30 1.6928664   
11  1:12:31 2.8167094   trip    3.300793
12  1:12:32 3.7848781   trip    3.300793
13  1:12:33 0.4496923
```

thx for your help

Comment: On the second trip, how do you calulate `MEAN = 1.074582`?

Comment: Hi waldi, the MEAN is now correct. The "mean" column is the new column I want. I seperated it into to tables (sample data and desired data).

Comment: currently I try to write a for loop and check if the value of type i and the value of type i + 1 is the same. And if so, i will write an ID in a new column. And the ID is always the same as long as the comparision is TRUE. But I have over 170 mio observations... this is definitely not time efficient..afterwards I could calculate the mean with an ifelse statement (over the ID and TYPE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rleid` from `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
data <- read.table(text=
"Time    speedms     type   
1:12:21 1.0978790   'trip'  
1:12:22 1.5707432   'trip'  
1:12:23 1.0745824   NA
1:12:24 1.1682027   NA
1:12:25 1.3859502   NA
1:12:26 0.9657960   'trip'  
1:12:27 1.2591893   'trip'  
1:12:28 2.0004471   'trip'  
1:12:29 2.2239989   NA
1:12:30 1.6928664   NA
1:12:31 2.8167094   'trip'  
1:12:32 3.7848781   'trip'  
1:12:33 0.4496923   NA",header=T) 


setDT(data)

data[,MEAN:=fifelse(type=='trip',mean(speedms), NA_real_), by = rleid(type)]
data
#>        Time   speedms type     MEAN
#>  1: 1:12:21 1.0978790 trip 1.334311
#>  2: 1:12:22 1.5707432 trip 1.334311
#>  3: 1:12:23 1.0745824 <NA>       NA
#>  4: 1:12:24 1.1682027 <NA>       NA
#>  5: 1:12:25 1.3859502 <NA>       NA
#>  6: 1:12:26 0.9657960 trip 1.408477
#>  7: 1:12:27 1.2591893 trip 1.408477
#>  8: 1:12:28 2.0004471 trip 1.408477
#>  9: 1:12:29 2.2239989 <NA>       NA
#> 10: 1:12:30 1.6928664 <NA>       NA
#> 11: 1:12:31 2.8167094 trip 3.300794
#> 12: 1:12:32 3.7848781 trip 3.300794
#> 13: 1:12:33 0.4496923 <NA>       NA
```

Comment: thx! That worked perfectly. Saw the fifelse function the first time. Learned even more.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr method:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(temp = with(rle(type), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>% 
  mutate(mean = if_else(is.na(type), NA_real_, mean(speedms))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp)

# A tibble: 13 x 4
   Time    speedms type   mean
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1 1:12:21   1.10  trip   1.33
 2 1:12:22   1.57  trip   1.33
 3 1:12:23   1.07  NA    NA   
 4 1:12:24   1.17  NA    NA   
 5 1:12:25   1.39  NA    NA   
 6 1:12:26   0.966 trip   1.41
 7 1:12:27   1.26  trip   1.41
 8 1:12:28   2.00  trip   1.41
 9 1:12:29   2.22  NA    NA   
10 1:12:30   1.69  NA    NA   
11 1:12:31   2.82  trip   3.30
12 1:12:32   3.78  trip   3.30
13 1:12:33   0.450 NA    NA
```